# C# type of generic class that inherits from abstract class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics, inheritance

I'm struggling to find an easy way of getting the type based on a generic class that inherits from an abstract class.

I have this hierarchy:

```
public abstract class BaseItemData {}

public abstract class WearableItemData : BaseItemData {}

----
public class EquipmentItemData : WearableItemData {}

public class WeaponItemData : WearableItemData {}

----

public class Item<T> : ScriptableObject {}

public class EquipmentItem : Item<EquipmentItemData> { }

public class WeaponItem : Item<WeaponItemData> { }
```

With this, I would like to get all Scriptable Objects Assets at editor time.
im bulding custom editor with Odin Inspector and would like to add all assets of type `Item` to the tree
but I can't do because of the generic type that need to be passed to `Item`

```
   protected override OdinMenuTree BuildMenuTree() {
        OdinMenuTree tree = new OdinMenuTree();
    
    // THIS WORKS
        tree.AddAllAssetsAtPath("TEMPLATES/Weapons", "Assets/Scriptable/Templates", typeof(WeaponItem));
        tree.AddAllAssetsAtPath("TEMPLATES/Equipment", "Assets/Scriptable/Templates", typeof(EquipmentItem));

   // BUT I WOULD LIKE TO HAVE SOMETHING MORE LIKE THIS

        tree.AddAllAssetsAtPath("TEMPLATES", "Assets/Scriptable/Templates", typeof(Item)); // or typeof(Item<WearableItemData>)
    
        return tree;
      }
```

These works

```
typeof(Item<WeaponItemData>)
typeof(Item<EquipmentItemData>)
typeof(WeaponItem)
typeof(EquipmentItem)
```

But these don't as I thought they would ( apparently abstract class don't work???)

```
typeof(Item<BaseItemData>)
typeof(Item<WearableItemData>)
```

How can I make so `typeof(Item<WearableItemData>)` would work? (May it be Odin specific?? (editor time?))

Comment: What do you mean by "get all objects"? How are you getting them?

Comment: i'm getting all typeof as expected. Maybe the question needs to be reworked

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Why are you trying to use `typeof(Item<WearableItemData>)`? Are you trying to get all **assets** of that scriptable object, or all (runtime) **instances** of that scriptable object? Also, is this for code that should only be used at edit time? Or is this code that needs to run in game? Need more information. Intent behind question is too vague to offer most helpful advice.

Comment: forgot the link: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/405359)

Comment: I updated with some more context. Basically, I have this issue with Odin Inspector right now but I wonder if I would also experience it at runtime when doing Inventory setup

Comment: I've never used odin before. This is kind of a hack but what if you make a dummy class `public class ItemBase : ScriptableObject {/*nothing*/}`, then inherit from it with `public class Item<T> : ItemBase {/*...*/}`, then you can use `typeof(BaseItem)`? I don't know how odin is using the `Type` parameter under the hood.

Comment: Yeah, I just did that and it worked. Seems a little like workaround/hacky but worked at least!
Hope that at runtime it won't cause me this problem.
Feel free to post as an answer I would mark it as solution unless someone could propose something else within the bounty period

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a class for all of the non-generic stuff (or just leave empty):

```
public class ItemBase : ScriptableObject 
{
    /* nothing, or non-generic stuff here */
}
```

Then, inherit from it for the generic item you have now:

```
public class Item<T> : ItemBase 
{
    /*...*/
}
```

Then, you can use `tree.AddAllAssetsAtPath("TEMPLATES", "Assets/Scriptable/Templates", typeof(ItemBase));`

Comment: Actually not a "hack" at all .. I use this quite often when I have generic base classes .. simply put everything that is not generic into the non-generic base and only put the generic stuff into the generic one. This way the pattern is quite powerful .. you can e.g. simply use `Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<ItemBase>()` this way without having to provide the generic type ;)

Comment: yeah it's more also in combination with generic interfaces and a non-generic base interface .. same principle

Comment: It is btw also completely legitimate to have a non-generic and a generic type with the same name so here e.g. `Item : ScriptaleObject` and `Item<T> : Item` ;)

Comment: Yeah ^^ just like me when I saw this the first time .. though it makes sense .. it is basically quite similar to method overloads ..  it's also the only case where all "overloads" go into the same script file for me :'D

Comment: It's interesting to me, because afaik you can't do that in java or c++ with their generics/templates. neat stuff

Comment: This is called a marker interface and is generally considered an antipattern.